# How to replace last two cells values in a table with a string using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  <table>
     <tr>
      <td>aaaa</td>
      <td>bbbb</td>
      <td>cccc</td>
      <td>dddd</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

In this above table, how can i replace last two cells values with a string "abcd"

Comment: Do you want to replace the values in the last 2 cells of the table, or of the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the text of both cells at once by passing a negative start index to [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$("td").slice(-2).text("abcd");
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Frederic. It is working fine. How can we implement same task using table id

Comment: @Hearaman, you only need to include an id selector, such as `$("#yourTableId td").slice(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

The following will replace the values in the last two cells, but I'm not sure that's what you really want:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var i = cells.length;
cells[--i].innerHTML = 'abcd';
cells[--i].innerHTML = 'abcd';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('td').eq(-2).html('this is the second to last')
  $('td').eq(-1).html('this is the last')
```

That should work (you could use :last to get the last as well).

Comment: @qwertymk, negative indices are supported by the `eq()` method but not by the `:eq()` selector.